# Java within thread reordering of instructions on the same variable

Tags: java, multithreading, java-memory-model

After reading through JLS and looking through multiple scenarios I can't get quite right which rules does the Java Memory models obeys for intra-thread semantics

Consider this code just for example purpose:

```
public class CharIndexer {
    public Map<char, int> charLastIndex;

    public void changeCount(String phrase) {
        Map<char, int> newCharLastIndex = new HashMap<char, int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
            newCharLastIndex.put(s.charAt(i),i);
        }

        charLastIndex = newCharLastIndex;
    }
}
```

In a scenario with multiple threads holding a reference to the same instance of CharIndexer, reading the field charLastIndex while one of them invokes changeCount method.

Would it be a valid reordering if the assignment to the charLastIndex field, the last assignment on the method, was done before the for block?

This would make possible for the reading threads to see a Map which was still not populated.

While I agree the visibility guarantee should be made explicit with a volatile keyword, do the intra-thread semantics allow such reordering?

Single-thread execution of both orders grant the same results, but which rules do govern the intra-thread reordering that would avoid the reordering of the two for blocks in this implementation:

```
public class CharIndexer {
    public Map<char, int> charLastIndex;

    public void changeCount(String phrase) {
        Map<char, int> newCharLastIndex = new HashMap<char, int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
            newCharLastIndex.put(s.charAt(i),i);
        }

        // just changing values around
        foreach(Map.Entry<char,int> charEntry : newCharLastIndex) {
             charEntry.setValue(charEntry.getValue() * 10);
        }

        charLastIndex = newCharLastIndex;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to wrap my head around how far does the JIT analysis goes or if I'm ignorant of the particular set of rules for intra-thread semantics.

Comment: BTW, "intra-thread" means within a single thread.  The reordering within a single thread is always "program order" in Java.  In other words you'll never see any reordering visible within a single thread.

Answer (score 1):

With no happen-before boundaries or synchronization blocks in effect, the order of operations, as seen by another thread, can be out-of-order.

The best way to explain it, is that your `HashMap` object and your `CharIndexer` object may be located in different parts of computer memory.

On a multiple-CPU server, memory access is cached independently by each CPU, so when CPU #1 run the `changeCount()` method, all it's actions are done in the CPU 1 Cache.

Eventually, that cache is flushed to main RAM, and other CPU's can see it, once they reload *their* cache from main RAM.

But, the cache section holding the `HashMap`, and the cache section holding the `CharIndexer`, may not flush+reload at the same time. So CPU #2 may see the update to `CharIndexer` *before* is sees the update to the referenced `HashMap`.

That is why you need to ensure that the building of the `HashMap` *happens-before* the assignment of the `charLastIndex` value, or that both will *happen-before* any use of the `charLastIndex` value.

Comment: I understand there are no guarantees that CPU #2 sees the effects of CPU #1 on `CharIndexer`. 

What I'm missing is how can the `charLastIndex` assignment be reordered but not the two for blocks in second code snippet. @Andreas What's into play to make one valid but the other invalid?

Comment: Don't understand you. What do you believe is valid vs invalid? Both code examples can behave unpredictably if `charLastIndex` is accessed by other threads without synchronization or happens-before boundaries.